# How does 3 phase power distribution work?

Tags: power

Hey so I have had trouble understanding this. On the power poles near my house, I see 4 wires attached to the power poles. Are these the 3 phase lines and a neutral wire?
I noticed that on each pole near a house, one line runs from a transformer to the home. Are one of the 3 phases and the neutral wire being run to the home to supply single phase AC?
Are the high voltage lines 3 phase as well? I noticed that these lines are far above the ground and that they hVe more than 4 wires associated with them.
Finally, what are the loads in this 3 phase distribution system? If the loads are houses and businesses then how are they arranged in a Wye or delta formation?

Any help in understanding this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the power lines in question? Most modern distribution in the USA is 240 VAC single phase which has two 120 V insulated hot wires and a grounded neutral which is often a bare steel cable around which the hot wires are twisted.

Comment: I remember en.wikipedia's articles on power distribution to be half decent, including the use of multiple conductors for a single phase in high voltage transmission. This looks overly broad for an SE question, starting with a handful of questions in a single question post.

Comment: Can you say what country this is in?  These things vary a lot between countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are 3 phases and the neutral cable. If the load on all 3 phases is the same, then the current over neutral is zero.

We have here often only 3 wires at the medium voltage pylon, the neutral line is here the earth.
This 3 wires are going into a transformer and generate 3 phases 400V AC.

The three 400V wires are going into the household with the earth/neutral-wire (in German we call it PEN = PE + Neutral) line. This one PEN wire is splitted into two wires (PE and Neutral) inside of the meter box. The neutral is the way to generate 3x 230V. The Earth (PE) is the protection wire, if a current flow over this cable back to the transformer, then the difference between the phase and neutral is not zero any more and the RCD circuit breaker is triggered.

Comment: @greybeard - I have try to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In my area (Vancouver BC) three phase 13,200 V lines run North in a nearby street.  At each East/West lane there is a single HV wire connected to one of the three phases.  Every second or third power pole along the lane has a transformer to step the HV down to 120/240V single phase to feed to the individual homes. One transformer may feed 6 or 8 homes.

The HV wires are at the top of the power poles, and there is a grounded ground/neutral wire lower on the poles, along with the two 120 V "hot" wires providing 120/240 V to the homes.

Below the 120/240V wires are telephone and cable TV cables.

Comment: It is always interesting to see how different this is solved in other countries. Our cable TV cables are buried in the ground and have nothing to do with the power poles. At the top of the big power poles there is a glass-fibre data line, in the past they used it only for the communication with the other power-stations and substations, today it is used for the internet connections for cities too.

Comment: @MikroPower:  I expect that newer housing developments here will have power and other utilities underground.  My neighbourhood was built up in the 1920's.